# How to display an integer number in HTML input tag without separators like comma or point?

Tags: html, number-formatting

I want to display an integer number in html which I get from a rest api call as json response. But in my HTML page it is displayed with a comma. So now when I want to accept the fields and save my record, the field shows a error message: "Please enter a valid schema".

That's my code:

HTML:

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="disabledTextInput" class="form-label">Pages</label>
    <input type="number" class="form-control" name="pages" value="${book.pages}">
</div>
```

The field in json:

```
"pageCount": 1531
```

That's the result with separator:

[image]

Comment: The format of the displayed number depends on the regional settings of the user's OS. If you want to get the number as a Number (without formatting), you can use the `input`'s `valueAsNumber` property.

Answer (score 0):

Hoply can help. You can add this code, just adjust it with your code

```
<?php
//hide comma with replace function
$book_pages= str_replace(",", "", $book.pages);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry my bad, I forgot to tell that is written in FreeMaker.

So the solution is just writing it with some FreeMarker logic:

```
<input type="number" class="form-control" name="pages" value="${book.pages?c}">
```